# Excel import through ADO.Net in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, multilingual, import-from-excel

Anybody please help me I am unable to import Excel file data in `SQL Server Database`. The excel file data is in multi languages the data which is in English is uploaded properly but the data which is in other language is readed but in an encoded format.

Please, let me know how can I import multi language excel file in database?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask])

Comment: maybe you have problem with **collation** in SQL Server, please give more information or sample of codes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `collation` used for datatable in SQL server. You may need to update data type for imported data table in SQL server to support different encodings. Make use of [`nvarchar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) data type for column for which different language input expected.

You can do on non primary key fields:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName]
ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] nvarchar(N) null
```

On the primary key fields it will not work - you will have to recreate the table.

Make sure that the length doesn't exceed 4000 since the maximum for `VARCHAR` is 8000 while `NVARCHAR` is only 4K